# Google Play Services - Where is SafeParcelable?

Tags: android, google-play-services, buck

Which granular play-services contains the following class?

*com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable*

I've currently got the following dependencies, but I get an error where it can't find SafeParcelable.

- play-services-base-8.4.0
- play-services-location-8.4.0
- play-services-maps-8.4.0

In case it matters, I'm using Buck for my Android project, and including these aars directly from my m2repository.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have confirmed that  the class  `com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable` exists in *play-services-base-8.4.0.jar*.

However, you indicated that you are using AAR files, not JARs.  I search the contents of these and found that this class now (version 8.4.0) exists in the following AAR file:

*play-services-basement-8.4.0.aar*

Comment: I haven't come across a jar, I'm using play-services-base-8.4.0.aar. But I'm assuming it should be the same?

Comment: I looked at the AAR file, and it has all classes in an embedded jar file, classes.jar.  However this jar file did not contain the class in question.  Stand by and I will see if I can figure this out...